# call function in jquery plugin from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i call a JQuery plugin function from within an iframe?

```
 (function($){

         $.fn.jqueryEx = function() {

               function CallThisFunctionFromIframe(){
               }

         }



 })(jQuery);
```

### Edit

The iframe is on the same domain as parent document.

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as the parent document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function($){

     $.fn.jqueryEx = function() {


         $.fn.jqueryEx .CallThisFunctionFromIframe= function() {

             alert('hello');

         }  

     }


 })(jQuery);
```

Call this from within the iframe

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     window.parent.$.fn.jqueryEx.CallThisFunctionFromIframe();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you this approach. Just wrap the logic you want to call into the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
    function CalledFromChild() {
        // Stuff triggered from child
        alert("What ever");
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

and in the iframe you can do so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    window.parent.CalledFromChild();
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to use the functionality of jquery in the iframe, i.e. you want to make your say textbox to be a calendar, then you have to import the libraries into the iframe too. Physically browser will not donwload the libraries twice so you just add the reference.